# Android placing a view above another

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have in my screen 5 components: space, listview, space, listview and space, as shown in the left image.

I want to be able to place another space (in red) above all of these components mentioned. All of them are lying inside a LinearLayout.

I tried to use another LinearLayout (with the space) inside the root LinearLayout, but it only caused bugs.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="#009900"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.myname.appname.NameActivity">

<Space
    android:id="@+id/space1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#00CC00"
    android:divider="#009900"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:scrollbars="none" />


<Space
    android:id="@+id/space2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_width="124dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#e6e600"
    android:divider="#009900"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:scrollbars="none" />

<Space
    android:id="@+id/space3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Impossible to say what the problem is without seeing your xml

Comment: Set `android:orientation="vetical"` on your `LinearLayout`. [The default is horizontal](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:orientation) so making your first view to match_parent for width will take up the whole space

Comment: *"but it only caused bugs."*...you should explain what these "bugs" are so we can better help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With what you have there, you need a nested linear layout to hold everything.  It will look like this:

```
<LinearLayout orientation="vertical">
-- put your top container here --
-- put your existing linearlayout AND its contents here --
</LinearLayout>
```

The outer container will be vertically oriented, while the second one will be horizontal, like you already have it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Got a simple and tested layout solution right here. Refer to code below :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#efe304"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.myname.appname.NameActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#ff0900"
        android:paddingTop="20px" >

        <Space
            android:id="@+id/space1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="20px" >

        <Space
            android:id="@+id/space1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#efe304"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_width="124dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#009900"
            android:divider="#009900"
            android:dividerHeight="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

        <Space
            android:id="@+id/space1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#efe304"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_width="124dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#009900"
            android:divider="#009900"
            android:dividerHeight="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

        <Space
            android:id="@+id/space1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#efe304"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```